# Python IDE with parameter hints

Tags: python, ide, microsoft-excel

I want a python IDE that shows function arguments as does Excel. Example:

In Excel, I can type "=IF" and the formula will show what arguments, in which sequence, Excel wants to finish the function. Example:

=IF

shows =IF(____________,_________________,___________________)

```
      logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false]
```

Super handy, eh? What python editor will show this for moi?

Comment: I changed the title, please change it back if you don't like it. You are looking for `parameter hints` and not only Excel has these. Just Google for `python ide with parameter hints`